# How to change product display size on product pages

Tags: shopify

I would really like to change the default display size for images on my products pages. My theme has them taking up half the page width and it just washes out the page. Is there an easy way to do this?

Also, any advice on if you think it is a good idea would be appreciated, it really annoys me but maybe it's just me!

My site is https://brantees.com/products/wheat-field-grain-creative-artistic-unisex-tee-shirt

Comment: Can you please share theme name??

Answer (score 0):

First of all check if there's an option for that in the Customizer.
If not -- you'll have to go into the product template and edit it.
The `div` with the image is a column defined as

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12  clearfix product--images">
```

`col-lg-6` means it takes up 6 columns out of 12 on a large screen.

`col-md-6` -- 6 out of 12 on a medium screen.

`col-sm-12` -- 12 out 12 (the whole width) on a mobile screen.

You can change these numbers, but if you decrease numbers in the left columns -- increase them in the right if you want the two columns to take up 100% of the page width.